# If every bounded subset of metric space is separable, then metric space is separable

Tags: general-topology

In my functional analysis class I was given a problem from general topology:

*Prove that if in metric space every bounded subspace is separable, then the space is separable*

I have also found out that for metric spaces separability equivalent to the existence of countable base in standard metric space topology. I tried to prove this statement by construction countable base from countable bases of bounded subsets. Honestly, I do not know how to begin the proof, because, obviosly, I can not simply take a union of countable bases of all bounded subsets, because the number of bounded subsets can be uncountable. Maybe here is some trick about how to construct countable base from all this countable bases of bounded subsets, so I ask for a hint. This problem looks simple, but I do not have ideas how to begin.

Comment: Fix a point $x$, each of the balls $B_n(x)$ centered at $x$ of radius $n\in\Bbb N$ contains a countable dense subset $D_n$, $\bigcup B_n(x)$ covers the whole space, and $\bigcup D_n$ is a countable dense set in the whole space

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti thank you! now i see that my question was very silly....

Comment: @Alessandro Codenotti: Somewhat in the spirit of Linderholm's 1971 book [**Mathematics Made Difficult**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_Made_Difficult) ([copy at archive.org](https://archive.org/details/mathematics-made-difficult)), another proof can be obtained by observing that every metric space is topologically equivalent to a bounded metric space, and separability is equivalent to 2nd countability in metric spaces, and 2nd countability is preserved under topological equivalence. At least assuming I'm not overlooking something in all this $\ldots$